# Are WiFi extenders considered to be non-professional?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I asked [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/457569/setting-up-wifi-extenders-is-it-possible-to-daisy-chain-them) question, which got a great answer, but was voted to close. My question is, why? From what I can see, it appears to be well within the scope of the site (networking). Are the use of WiFi extenders considered to be non-professional grade?

Answer (score 6):

While your situation is pretty unprofessional, you're essentially guaranteed to have long term issues due to the hardware/configuration, I don't think it's off-topic for SF. I've re-opened the question, though there's nothing stopping people from closing it again.

I'm a bit dismayed that none of the people who voted to close left any comment with their reasoning. Usually someone leaves a comment, unless it's painfully obvious (which isn't the case here).

Comment: From my observations, the /review workflow makes close-and-forget processing much easier. I suspect that's part of it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that's what I had to work with, so I wanted to make sure it would work as well as possible.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't worry about it.  The natives are pretty trigger-happy with the close votes these days, and they're trying to "clear out" the review queues, so you probably just got swept up in that.  The absence of downvotes is probably a better indication that your question's decent.

Comment: Think its time for an announcement similar to this? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one

Comment: @TheLQ - I like that annoucement